# Spring app not deploying in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-mvc

I've some kind of weird and frustrating bug wich block debug mode. It started suddenly and i can't get rid of it even trying to revert last changes.

When running my webApp in normal mode, it deploy and run properly, but when running it in debug mode, it can't finish, my last stacktrace info sais:

```
[...] INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/mvc/i18n.xml]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2222af8c: defining beans [gruposTrabajoServiceImpl,usuarioServiceImpl,vacacionesServiceImpl,calendarioServiceImpl,administracionServiceImpl,empleadosServiceImpl,aeropuertosServiceImpl,rotacionesServiceImpl,rotacionesController,empleadosController,vacacionesController,aeropuertosController,loginController,includeController,administracionController,gruposTrabajoController,informesController,festivoDAOImpl,empleadoDAOImpl,limitacionDAOImpl,habilidadEmpDAOImpl,fpCalendarioEmpDAOImpl,autorizacionDAOImpl,minimosPatronDAOImpl,ceAnoEmpDAOImpl,poaUpaDAOImpl,turnoRotacionDAOImpl,patronRotacionDAOImpl,anoEmpDAOImpl,grupoTrabajoDAOImpl,incidenciaDiaDAOImpl,telefonoEmpDAOImpl,usuarioDAOImpl,escalaDAOImpl,limitacionEmpDAOImpl,visibleCntMinimosDAOImpl,configuracionContratoEscalaDAOImpl,puntuacionDAOImpl,vpCalendarioEmpDAOImpl,usuarioEscalaDAOImpl,anoEscalaDAOImpl,vpCupoGtDAOImpl,habilidadDAOImpl,formacionEmpDAOImpl,dominioDAOImpl,formacionDAOImpl,tipoTurnoDAOImpl,incidenciaDAOImpl,observacionDiaDAOImpl,rotacionDAOImpl,turnoDAOImpl,calendario,mes,perfilAspect,excelEscala,excelAnual_,excelEscala_,globalConstants,dominioConstants,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,messageSource,localeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4349e631
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Using MessageSource [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource: basenames=[messages]]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@6e3f6d73]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2222af8c: defining beans [gruposTrabajoServiceImpl,usuarioServiceImpl,vacacionesServiceImpl,calendarioServiceImpl,administracionServiceImpl,empleadosServiceImpl,aeropuertosServiceImpl,rotacionesServiceImpl,rotacionesController,empleadosController,vacacionesController,aeropuertosController,loginController,includeController,administracionController,gruposTrabajoController,informesController,festivoDAOImpl,empleadoDAOImpl,limitacionDAOImpl,habilidadEmpDAOImpl,fpCalendarioEmpDAOImpl,autorizacionDAOImpl,minimosPatronDAOImpl,ceAnoEmpDAOImpl,poaUpaDAOImpl,turnoRotacionDAOImpl,patronRotacionDAOImpl,anoEmpDAOImpl,grupoTrabajoDAOImpl,incidenciaDiaDAOImpl,telefonoEmpDAOImpl,usuarioDAOImpl,escalaDAOImpl,limitacionEmpDAOImpl,visibleCntMinimosDAOImpl,configuracionContratoEscalaDAOImpl,puntuacionDAOImpl,vpCalendarioEmpDAOImpl,usuarioEscalaDAOImpl,anoEscalaDAOImpl,vpCupoGtDAOImpl,habilidadDAOImpl,formacionEmpDAOImpl,dominioDAOImpl,formacionDAOImpl,tipoTurnoDAOImpl,incidenciaDAOImpl,observacionDiaDAOImpl,rotacionDAOImpl,turnoDAOImpl,calendario,mes,perfilAspect,excelEscala,excelAnual_,excelEscala_,globalConstants,dominioConstants,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,messageSource,localeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4349e631
```

It always stays in the same place Pre-instantiating singletons in...

I've tried running my app in both Tomcat 7 and weblogic 10.3.4 but i get the same result.

Any idea? I'm lost without debug mode.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I suppose it hangs indefinitely without throwing any exceptions. In that case, could you take an thread dump of the application by pressing Ctrl-Break in the console, or using your IDE's thread dump functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long shot, but maybe you added some breakpoints to the code of one of your classes, and when in debug mode, the execution waits for you to explicitly signal it to continue?

You probably have some debug window open. What does it show there?

Comment: Thank you for both for your interest. I've solved it, it seems to be one of this weird eclipse stuff. I just clean and remove both servers and set them again and now it seems to work. I'm sorry but I still ignore the real cause, but at least I now can go on with my work. This 'forum' and this comunity make me feel sooo good.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the exact same issue with STS IDE version 3.6.4 and it seems that it was stopped at a breakpoint without highlighting it. Thus I was unawered of the situation. I cleared all of the breakpoints and it magically works now.